# haproxy - redirect specific domain/path to other domain

Tags: haproxy

i need redirect request from specific domain/path to other domain with same path, eg.

domain.com/foo/everything --> example.com/foo/everything

I think need use `url_reg` but I can't understand how to handle the redirect, maybe it could be such a thing?

```
acl redirect-foo   url_reg -i      ^domain.com\/foo\/*
http-request redirect code 301 location http://example.com/foo/ if redirect-foo
```

but obviously it doesn't work, thank anyone who can help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following snipplet

```
acl host_match hdr(host) -i domain.com
acl path_match path_beg  -i /foo/

http-request redirect code 301 location http://example.com/%[capture.req.uri] if host_match path_match
```

The acl's are described in the Documentation and in following Blog post.

[Using ACLs to form conditions](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#7.2)
[Introduction to HAProxy ACLs](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-acls/)

Documentation for [capture.req.uri](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#7.3.6-capture.req.uri)

Comment: If I would redirect without `/foo/`? ie domain.com/foo/everything --> example.com/everything

Comment: Then I would try `%[capture.req.uri,regsub(/foo,)]` Documentation for [regsub](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#7.3.1-regsub)